# If $A=Ae\oplus A(1-e)$, is $e$ a nontrivial idempotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My book says "it is easy to see that $A$ (a commutative ring) has an idempotent $e\neq 0,1$ if and only if it is a direct sum of rings $A=A_1\oplus A_2$ with $A_1=Ae$ and $A_2=A(1-e)$."

I know the $\implies$ implication, but if $A=Ae\oplus A(1-e)$, why is $e$ a nontrivial idempotent? I tried writing $e=ae+b(1-e)$ for $a,b\in A$ and squaring, but nothing cancels correctly. I also tried computing $e(1-e)$ with $1-e=1-ae-b(1-e)$, but again nothing cancels nicely.

Comment: Dear Cye: I agree with you. Which book is it? (Welcome to MSE, and $+1$ for your nice question!)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Thanks! It's the first few sentences of section 1.11 on page 28 of Miles Reid's Undergraduate Commutative Algebra.

Comment: Dear Cye: You're right. Here is a [preview](http://books.google.fr/books?id=mUL1us0mRrAC&lpg=PP1&dq=intitle%3Acommutative%20inauthor%3Areid&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q=intitle:commutative%20inauthor:reid&f=false). I think it's just a typo. The correct statement is (I think) "iff it is a nontrivial direct sum of two *ideals*". ($A_1$ and $A_2$ are not subrings, but ideals. These ideals have a ring structure, but the inclusion is not a ring morphism.) (But it is the direct *product* of the two rings.)

Comment: @Pierre: If $e$ is an idempotent, then $Ae$ *is* a ring, and a subset. Whether it is a subring depends on whether you require rings to have unity (but subring isn't mentioned in the question). Of course, I really don't like the usage of "direct sum" in this fashion since it ought to imply a coproduct of sorts, but unfortunately this seems to be a common conventional usage too. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is OK, I think. If $A = Ae \oplus A(1-e)$, then consider $e(1-e) = (1- e)e.$ This is in $Ae \cap A(1-e) = \{ 0\},$ so we must have $e(1-e) =0$ and hence $e = e^2.$ I think you should require both $Ae$ and $A(1-e)$ to be non-zero, though, strictly speaking to exclude $e \in \{0,1 \}.$

Comment: Dear Geoff: $+1$! I think Reid's phrase "direct sum of rings" is unfortunate. You may have a look at my comment.